# Comparing SELECT queries of a single table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with a single table of vehicles, consisting of about 2000-3000 rows and contains a vehicle make/model along with a status (there are many different statuses, I am concerned about 'T' and 'Y'). I want to create a query that will return the count of vehicles that have the same make/model as entries but different status. For example:

```
INSERT INTO my_db(make, model, status) VALUES ("BMW", "6-SERIES", "T")
INSERT INTO my_db(make, model, status) VALUES ("BMW", "6-SERIES", "Y")
INSERT INTO my_db(make, model, status) VALUES ("BMW", "6-SERIES", "Y")
```

I want my query to return "1" because we have a BMW 6-Series that has been matched with a T and Y at some point. How can I accomplish this? I have attempt to make two separate tables and do a join, and also tried a subselect, but I can't seem to get it working.

edit: I should clarify - I only want it adding to the count if make/model has an entry for both T and Y, not different statuses in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count(*)` and `exists` if you want to count rows:

```
select count(*)
from my_db d1
where exists (select 1
              from my_db d2
              where d2.make = d.make and d2.model = d.model and
                    d2.status <> d.status
             );
```

If you want to count make/model combinations, I would suggest two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select make, model
      from t
      group by make, model
      having min(status) <> max(status)
     ) mm;
```

Comment: Hm, first one is definitely close but I need it to only give one count per match (for example the inserts above should only return 1, not 2). The second one is giving me a syntax error around the first line. Thanks for the help.

Comment: nevermind! I was able to figure it out from your comment. thanks again!